# Devel::Cover - Impossible to mark branch as uncoverable

Tags: perl, devel-cover

I'm honestly not sure if this is a bug or me missing something.

`Devel::Cover` ignores my `# uncoverable branch true` based on a previous condition somehow.

I have 2 files - `Test` and `Test2` - the `uncoverable` is in `Test`.

Now when the *trigger condition (see below)* is not commented out I get 50% branch coverage that looks like this:

[image: messed up coverage]

Now comment out the *trigger condition* and run everything again and I get:

[image: expected coverage]

The branch is now properly ignored as uncoverable. The only thing that was changed was commenting out the *trigger condition*.

I really don't understand this behavior - if anybody would be willing to try this out to see if this is me not understanding something or a bug.

Disclaimer: I'm no perl guru :) I tried to simplify this more but I could not reproduce it otherwise - even simplification of this is appreciated - maybe it will help trace to the root cause of it.

**EDIT**: I made this repo to make this easier to reproduce: https://github.com/lukaskuzmiak/Devel--Cover_coverage_issue_PoC

```
package My::Test;

use 5.026;
use strict;
use warnings;

use My::Test2;


sub test {

    my $test2 = My::Test2->new({});

    if ($test2 > 1) { say 'something'; } # let's call this "trigger condition"

    # uncoverable branch true
    $test2->asdf(
        {
            variable => 'asdf'
        }
    ) or say 'something else';

    return 1;
}

1;
```

And a second `Test2`

```
package My::Test2;

use 5.026;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub asdf {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    return 1;
}

1;
```

Comment: I have verified this and it is 1.31, good point though, thanks. I'm going over open issues on Github, there are a few that possibly could have the same root cause but don't look similar on the first look. I'll try to narrow it down and update this based on the results.

Comment: Your code does not match your example output. It's also unnecessarily complicated. If you can strip it down to a *complete* runnable example that illustrates the problem, we can possibly help.

Comment: I tried to simplify it further, but I could no longer reproduce the issue. The screenshots are taken on this exact code - perl perhaps translates stuff internally? If you're referring to the "unless" that is not in my code. Anyway, I made a GitHub repo with all the sources to hopefully make it easier to reproduce.